# navbar not showing any link after bootstrap 4 alpha 6 installation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, navbar, bootstrap-4

I understand that they changed the navbar from the alpha 5 however I can't find what is breaking my previously working navbar.
If I resize the page to XS the hamburger appears and the links are there but what I get at > XS is a blue line with nothing.

The nav is declared as:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
    &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">My Project</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @if (Auth::check())
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
            @else
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
            @endif
            ///
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated navbar for alpha 6...

https://www.codeply.com/go/wMQvyBdLTi

The `navbar-toggleable-xs` has changed to `navbar-toggleable` and needs to go in the `navbar` element. The toggler will hide according the to the `navbar-toggleable` breakpoint so you can remove `hidden-sm-up`. Finally, add class `navbar-collapse` to the `collapse`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable bg-primary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
    &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">My Project</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @if (Auth::check())
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
            @else
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
            @endif
            ///
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

For Bootstrap 4 Beta, `navbar-toggleable-*` has changed to `navbar-expand-*`, `navbar-inverse` is now `navbar-dark`

Comment: how do you decide at what size the navbar collapses?

Comment: It's up to you. If your navbar has a lot of items, you may want to to collapse sooner at a larger breakpoint such as `navbar-toggleable-sm` or `navbar-toggleable-md` Also see [SO Bootstrap 4 Navbar docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/9090/migrating-to-bootstrap-4/28674/bootstrap-4-navbar#t=20170518173545184284)